# What can I use for analytics for my 50+ website network?

Tags: analytics

I was using Google Analytics but they have a 50 domain/account cap and instead of breaking them up into segmented groups I figured I'd ask everyone here if they have experience with something better.

Would obviously prefer free but just don't want to pay more than $25/month without a free trial.

It should be noted that I have already setup quantcast which is my first public analytics tool but that will take at least 4-6 days to begin showing numbers so I'm unsure if I'll like it,

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)?  It's not as polished as GA or other top-end stats packages, but it does a good job and contains all the right sorts of analytics data you'd likely want.  Plus, since it's open source, you can tweak the reporting and presentation so that it's customised specifically for your needs.

Comment: Oh, and it's - obviously - free.

Comment: extra plus is that it *looks* much fancier than comparable tools

Comment: As an update to this post, Piwik's latest release (v1.3) is actually quite polished and a worthwhile alternative to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

I went for [W3Counter](http://www.w3counter.com/), the pro version is only $10/month flat (I couldn't imagine anyone using their free product because of the differences) but I'm actually really liking it, real time is something I haven't seen before either and looking at the live Google Maps seeing visitors popup is semi-addicting.